# How to connect MOSS 2007 list with SSRS?

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, reporting-services, sharepoint-2007, ssrs-2008

I'm working with moss 2007. I need to do some SSRS reports. It seems that SSRS-Sharepoint connectivity via sharepoint services only allowed in same domain(as windows authentication is the only option allowed). I have sharepoint server running on different domain than the SSRS server domain. By the way, SSIS is not an option. Now I need to creat reports using the data on sharepoint list. I know I can do it by creating an app to retrieve and update the data to Sql Server and shedule it. But again I want to know is there any direct way. Could someone please give me some hints to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally I would suggest using the [Sharepoint List connection type](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee633650%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) as a data source in your report, however if the Sharepoint instance is in a different domain to the report server and there is no trust relationship between the domains to allow passing of credentials then I don't think that will work for you.

In that case I think your only option is to extract the data from the Sharepoint list by some other means (SSIS would be a good choice but you say that is not an option for you) into a location accessible from your report server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's what I thought. Pulling the data using a C# app from the sharepoint list services, and then update those to SQL server. To automate this I have to add a sheduled task on the SQL Server machine. But again It is a workaround. I thought there must be a direct way to do this.  Someone said that there will be solution using some ODBC connector(but they don't have more info on that).